# Percent width calculation in different browsers (Chrome Vs IE)

Tags: javascript, html, css, unslider

My application uses the [unslider.js](https://github.com/idiot/unslider/blob/master/src/js/unslider.js) file to generate and animate around 20 slides in my javascript based web application. 
Chrome calculates the width of the slide as 4.34783% whereas IE calculates the width as 4.34%. The slides are rendered perfectly in Chrome however the slides don't take up the entire available container space in IE. 
My question is - is there a difference in how IE and chrome calculate widths or deal with floating point percentages. What is the cause of different values of width. Is there a way to handle this inconsistency?

Both the browsers run on windows 7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Specify margin for your pages body tag.

Comment: And padding too